# Selecting marbles from two jars

Tags: probability

Jar $A$ contains $3$ red and $3$ black marbles, and Jar $B$ contains $4$ red and $6$ black marbles. If a marble is randomly selected from each Jar, what is the probability that the marbles will be the same color?

I'm having difficulty approaching this problem.  It seems like I should use Baye's Theorem to solve this problem, that is, let $A = \{\text{select a marble randomly from Jar A and Jar B}\}$ and $B = \{\text{the color of the marbles is the same}\}$.  I think I'm suppose to find $P(A|B)$ by Baye's Theorem.  However, I get stuck here as I need $P(A)$ and $P(B|A)$.  Perhaps my approach is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\,\mathbb{P}(\text{marbles are the same color})=\mathbb{P}(\text{both marbles are black or both marbles are red})\\
=&\,\mathbb{P}(\text{both marbles are black})+\mathbb{P}(\text{both marbles are red})\\
=&\,\mathbb{P}(\text{marble from A is black and marble from B is black})\\+&\,\mathbb{P}(\text{marble from A is red and marble from B is red})\\
=&\,\mathbb{P}(\text{marble from A is black})\times\mathbb{P}(\text{marble from B is black})\\+&\,\mathbb{P}(\text{marble from A is red})\times\mathbb{P}(\text{marble from B is red})\\
=&\,\frac{3}{6}\times\frac{6}{10}+\frac{3}{6}\times\frac{4}{10}=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}